# Jquery Datatables checkbox remember pagination issue

Tags: datatables

Im using datatables (server side randering) with checkbox plugin from Gyrocode.

```
var dTable2 = $('table.contracts-search-results').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "${someURL}",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.returnEmptyResult = '${returnEmptyResult}';
            },
        },
        searching: false,
        "dom": '<"top"iplB<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iplB<"clear">>',
        paging: true,
        pageLength: 0,
        displayStart: 50,
        "pagingType": "input",
        info: true,

        "buttons": [],
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": 
            {"targets": 7,
                "width": "75px",
                checkboxes: {
                                "selectRow": true,
                                "selectAll": false
                            },
                "stateSave": true,
                'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    var $this = this;

                        var selectedCon = '${con}';
                        var arrayOfCon = selectedCon.replace(/[\[\]\s']+/g, '').split(",");


                            $.map(arrayOfSelectedCon, function(conId, index) {
                                if(cellData == conId) {
                                    $this.api().cell(td).checkboxes.select();
                                }
                            });


                },
            },
            {
                "targets": [14, 15, 16],
                "visible": false
            },
        ],

        "select": {
            "style": "multi",
        },
        "language": {
            "decimal": ",",
            "thousands": ".",
            "url": themeUrl+"js/libs/dataTable/lang/german.json"
        },

        }
    }) ;
```

I have to pages. On first one I have datatables with configuration posted above. Second page I have another datatables with similar configuration. When user get to second page and choose some rows using checkboxes Im creating list od Ids and when user go back to first page I send Ids from second page to first one and select checkboxes on first page based on Ids from secound page.
The problem is that its working fine If all rows were on the same table page, but when user on secound page used pagination it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

use statesave: false as given,

```
"stateSave": false,
```

Comment: try it on second datatable only